# Run gVim with several parameters

Tags: vim

I want to open txt files in my krusader using gVim by default. I know, when I edit files from FTP, the command to open file must be like this:

1. `gvim -f %F`
   without this keys (`-f %F`), changes will no store to server. Also I want to open each file in it`s own tab, but not in another instance of **gVim** editor. To achieve this, I open files, using this command:
2. `gvim --remote-tab-silent`

I want to open files, using parameters from 1 and 2 example. When I try to change command to

```
gvim --remote-tab-silent -f %F
```

or

```
gvim -f %F --remote-tab-silent
```

It doesn't work properly. Who helps me to merge this 2 commands?

Comment: [Should you use tags in the title of your question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
gvim --remote-tab-wait-silent %F
```

-f seems to work only for local GUIs. For your remote server you need the wait version of the --remote command.

Comment: excellent! Thank you great! A whole day thying to resolve, but unfortunately(.